# Is there a general name for this algorithm running-sum-like algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, naming

I'm looking for a general name for the below algorithm/algorithmic trick.

```
xs = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]

ys = [xs[0]]
for i in range(1, len(xs)):
  if xs[i] == 1:
    ys.append(ys[i - 1] + 1)
  else:
    ys.append(ys[i - 1])

print ys
# prints: [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5]
```

That is, accumulate the number of 1's seen at some index in `xs`. Also, are there any conciser ways of doing this? Scala, Python, and Haskell answers are welcome.

Comment: Actually this is a "running count", not a "running sum".

Comment: @RBarryYoung: In the example, all the x values are 0 or 1 so they're the same.

Comment: @Nabb: Nope.  In the algorithm presented it explicitly adds either nothing or a literal 1.  It does ***not*** add the x value.  So the *algorithm* is a Count and not a Sum.

Comment: Running count seems more correct to me too. Thank you for your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell, that can be written more concise, and it's named a `scan` (more precisely a left scan, since it accumulates the intermediate results of a left fold),

```
scanl1 (\y x -> y + if x == 1 then 1 else 0) xs
```

and, for the running sum, even nicer,

```
scanl1 (+) xs
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so, it just too basic to make an acumulated Sum for the one values. Leave the Code as it is, its understandable.